# ConEmu reports "Injecting hooks into PID" failure

Tags: conemu

After a recent Windows 10 update, my ConEmu has started reporting the following message in a popup when I open a new DOS (cmd.exe) prompt:

> ConEmuC.M, PID=14284
>   Injecting hooks into PID=11432
>   FAILED, code=-703:0x00000005

I suspect this is caused by some kind of security update that was imposed on my machine, but I have no idea what.

This doesn't seem to be inhibiting any ConEmu functionality, but it is annoying that it pops up every time I open a new tab.

Does anyone know how I can solve this failure or suppress this popup?

(ConEmu version 180626 preview)

Answer (score 1):

Call to `VirtualAllocEx` is blocked due to `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`. This may be a result of your OS or antivirus update.

You may create an [issue](https://conemu.github.io/en/Issues.html) with details about your system.

Answer (score 1):

Execute as admin and the problem will be solved, this is some security problem, if you update your windows, then you need to open conEmu or cmder with administrator mode ALWAYS